# how to control the sound volume of my own android app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-audiomanager

I imagine the answer to this question must be something quite typical.  The point is that I have some buttons that play sounds when you click on them.  I want to control the sound volume.  How do I control the sound volume?  I am using the following code:

```
private fun playSound() {
  val sound = getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager 
  sound.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEY_CLICK, 1f)
}
```

Comment: Call `setStreamVolume()` on your `AudioManager`. Bear in mind that this sets the level of that stream for the *device*, so you need to to **reliably** set it back when you are done. Since doing that reliably is very difficult, apps generally should not be messing with volumes.

Comment: yes, it would be better not to modify the system volume. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#playSoundEffect(int,%20float`)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#playSoundEffect(int,%20float))

> `volume`  `float`: Sound effect volume. The volume value is a raw scalar so UI controls should be scaled logarithmically. If a volume of -1 is specified, the `AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC` stream volume minus 3dB will be used. NOTE: This version is for applications that have their own settings panel for enabling and controlling volume.

So you need to adjust that second parameter. I haven't used it, but it says that's a scalar so I'd imagine `1` is full volume? It doesn't mention any other value as a max constant or anything. `-1` gives you a sound a little quieter than the current media volume setting, if that's convenient. You'll need to play around with different values between 0 and 1 (I assume!) and see what you need

Comment: Hi, you're right. I was confused, I thought I could bypass the system volume. Maybe it is possible, but your answer is enough for me. Thank you.